# Ubuntu on HP xw4100 install fail

Tags: installation, 12.04, nvidia

Going around in circles trying to install 12.04 on a hp xw4100. Install starts gets to copying files then chokes. I suspect something todo with drivers? Google betrays me with nothing helpful.

O wise ones please help.

Comment: Are you using a CD/DVD or USB stick?  Are using 'LiveCD' from within Windows, or full install?  What steps have you completed?

Answer (score 0):

Open the SOFTWARE CENTER and install HPLIP first before you attempt to install that printer's driver. During the installation of the HPLIP software you get a prompt to discover your printers and download the driver directly fro HPs website. DO SO. You should be fine after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks bro but the xw4100 isn't a printer it's a pc workstation.  I'm having problems installing the os.

Comment: :-D Sorry, didn't realize that "minor detail".